# Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 Image Compress issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Am working on Work Execution app. How to compress the image size before saving the attachment since the attachment size limited to max 10MB.

Answer (score 2):

We have an iFix available that can be requested that will shrink this filesize of the default attachment on iOS.  Please open a PMR.

Comment: Hi, that's great. Does this also work for Android and Windows devices? It will only be a matter of time before our users run into the same problem there.

Comment: No, the fix is specifically for iOS where the file size is too large by default.   We haven't seen any issue with Android and Windows devices on this.  They tend to respect our original "quality" setting and keep their filesize relatively small. If you see any issues with Android/Windows please open a PMR.